# Does Task.Run() require async/await?

Tags: c#, .net

When creating a new task using `Task.Run()` is it required to mark the method as `async` and using `await` to resume program flow?

Or is it possible to just call `Task.Run()` and forget about the new thread? I.e., `Task.Run()` just returns and the new thread starts running independently.

Comment: What research have you done?  This [nice primer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh191443.aspx) might be useful for learning `async` and `await` if not.

Comment: Thanks, I really need to learn the async/await mechanism. But for now I just need some CPU-bound processing to run in a separate thread. `Task.Run()` seems the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is it possible to just call Task.Run() and forget about the new thread?

Yes, this is possible.  There is no requirement to handle the resulting `Task` or `Task<T>` in C#.  This means that you don't need to use `async` or `await`, as well.

That being said, "fire and forget" tasks are typically a sign of a poor design.  At the very minimum, it's typically a good idea to wrap the `Task` in something that will `await` it to handle and log exceptions.

Comment: Agreed. Instead of `async`-`await`, it's possible to use the `ContinueWith` method to deal with the task's result once it's finished (or failed).

Comment: This thread does some CPU-bound processing and uses a callback to notify status updates. So I am forgetting about it untill the processing is completed.

Comment: @sapito Use ContinueWith to do your "final" processing - but async/await makes that easier.

Comment: Yes, I may consider using async/await later. But the processing takes so long (hours) that it can be paused/resumed by the user. The user reads the results whenever he finds it convenient. So I wouldn't say there's something like a "final" processing. What I mean is that I am using the callback that the processing thread is calling after each iteration in order to manage (pause/resume/read provisional results) it.

Comment: @sapito If you are going to **eventually read** the result of a task, use `await`.  I don't see the benefit of using old style patterns with their contemporary counterparts `async+await` offers

Comment: @MickyDuncan It depends on the user. What this task is doing is creating/updating some big data (actually it's a genetic algorithm). The user is free to pause/resume the processing, read the data, convert it to a XLS file, etc. at any moment. So it's not like we have a "result of the task". Anyway, I may consider it later and refactor the code if it's convenient.